# Extend triangle to a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

The code below is how to construct a triangle. I want to extend this. The point E will be on the same line as the ray BA, having the same y-coordinate as point A and B, to the left of A. Angle BCE = 90. That means Angle ACE = 15 degrees. That means you need to extend the the horizontal line and the line will intersect with the angle constructed. 
Looking something like this:

[image]

Here is my code so far. Ignore the %code.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetkzobj{all}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,shapes}

\tikzset{
    myangle/.style={fill=green!20!white, draw=green!50!black,size=.3,opacity=.3},
    intnode/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Drawing the triangle and the coordinates
\draw coordinate[label=left:A] (a) --++(60:6) coordinate[label=above:B] (b);

\path[name path=ac] (a)--++(0:8.5);
\path[name path=bc] (b)--++(-45:8);
\path[name intersections={of = ac and bc, by=c}];
\node[anchor=west] at (c) {C};

\draw[use as bounding box] (a)--(b)--(c)--cycle;

% Drawing the coordinates S and T
%\coordinate (s) at ($(a)!0.75!(b)$);

%\path[name path=incls] (s) --++ (-10:5);
\path[name path=altbc] (b) -- (c);
%\path[name intersections={of = incls and altbc, by=t}]; 

%\draw[dashed] (s) -- (t) node[intnode,label={right:{\color{black}\scriptsize $T$}}] (t) {};

% Angles
\tkzFindAngle(a,b,c)
\tkzGetAngle{angleABC};
\FPround\angleABC\angleABC{0}
\tkzFindAngle(c,a,b)
\tkzGetAngle{angleCAB};
\FPround\angleCAB\angleCAB{0}
\tkzFindAngle(b,c,a)
\tkzGetAngle{angleBCA};
\FPround\angleBCA\angleBCA{0}
%\tkzFindAngle(a,s,t)
%\tkzGetAngle{angleAST};
%\FPround\angleAST\angleAST{0}

\tkzMarkAngle[myangle](a,b,c)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.4](a,b,c){\tiny $\angleABC^\circ$}

\tkzMarkAngle[myangle](c,a,b)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](c,a,b){\tiny $\angleCAB^\circ$}

\tkzMarkAngle[myangle](b,c,a)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.45](b,c,a){\tiny $\angleBCA^\circ$}

%\tkzMarkAngle[myangle](a,s,t)
%\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.4](a,s,t){\tiny $\angleAST^\circ$}

%\node[intnode,label={left:\scriptsize $S$}] at (s) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's interesting. Your screenshot looks very much like an accepted answer of this site. Why don't you share the link with us, or, even simpler, just use the code provided there?

Comment: @Zarko Guess it's your turn now. Somehow the OP forgot to mention that he got his pic from your nice answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411717/121799).

Comment: Yes, but I was asked by Zarko to add a new question. The code is not provided :)

Comment: I do not think that you should have suppressed this. @Zarko is a nice guy and provided you even with two very nice answers. So why can't you just acknowledge this in your post?

Comment: I dont understand. I am very thankful, and  I have said "Thank you so much." I am not that good in English, but I understood it that Zarko told me to add a new question, because we could not add the code in the comments,  Therefore I copied the picture, so that other people could understand what I was talking about.

Answer (score 4):

to whom who my be interested. my original code by which is generated image in [in my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410998/triangle-changing-vertices-draw-the-height-of-the-triangle/411717#411717) on follows-up question in your comment:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, backgrounds, calc, intersections, positioning, quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
myangle/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{angle radius=#1mm, angle eccentricity=#2,
                                 draw=#3!80!black, fill=#3!20!white},
   myangle/.default = 7/1.4/green
                        ]
% triangle's coordinates and edges
\coordinate[label=below:A]  (a);
\coordinate[label=below:B,right=8.5 of a] (b);
% triangle's coordinate determined by intersection
\path[name path=ac] (a) -- ++ ( 60:6.5);
\path[name path=bc] (b) -- ++ (135:8);
\path[name intersections={of = ac and bc, by=c}] node[label=C] at (c)  {};;
% triangle's edges
\draw (a)--(c)--(b)--cycle;
% draw perpedicular line for intersection E
\path[name path=ae] (a) -- ++ (-2.5,0);
\path[name path=ce] (c) -- ($(c)!7.7cm!-90:(b)$);
\draw[name intersections={of = ce and ae, by=e},red]
    (a) -- (e) node[below] {E} -- (c);
% angles at A, B, C
\pic [myangle, "\ang{60}"] {angle = b--a--c};
\pic [myangle, "\ang{45}"] {angle = c--b--a};
\pic [myangle, "\ang{75}"] {angle = a--c--b};
% angle for C-E and at E
\scoped[on background layer]
    \pic [myangle=12/1.2/red, "\ang{90}"] {angle = e--c--b};
\pic [myangle=7/1.4/red, "\ang{45}"] {angle = a--e--c};
% triangle height
\draw[dashed] (c) -- (c |- a) coordinate[label=below:D] (d);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]