Draw a geometric image with TikZ
I have no idea to drawing this image with TikZ:


Tikz: draw, node; libraries:, arrows.meta, angle

Read the online manual and show what you tried so far and where exactly you got stuck. There should already exist a lot of similar questions on this site. Thank you!

Please choose a title which describes the actual problem you face so that future users with the same problem will be able to find it.

Show us what you try so far. As starting point may serve https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411717

Thank to @Zarko for useful comment, answer to my question:
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, backgrounds, calc, intersections, positioning, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape,
myangle/.style args = {#1/#2}{angle radius=#1mm, angle eccentricity=#2,
                                 draw=black},
   myangle/.default = 7/1.4,
   > = Straight Barb
   ]

%
%   % Grids
%    \foreach \i in {\xMin,...,\xMax} {
%        \draw [very thin,gray] (\i,\yMin) -- (\i,\yMax)  node [below] at (\i,\yMin) {};
%    }
%    \foreach \i in {\yMin,...,\yMax} {
%        \draw [very thin,gray] (\xMin,\i) -- (\xMax,\i) node [left] at (\xMin,\i) {};
%    }


% triangle's coordinates and edges
\node[circle, inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=5pt]below:{$\large\boldsymbol{B}$}}] (B) at (0, 0) {};
%\coordinate[label=below:B]  (B);
\node[circle, inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=5pt]below:{$\large\boldsymbol{C}$}},right=7 of B] (C) {};
%\coordinate[label=below:C,right=7 of B] (C);
% triangle's coordinate determined by intersection
\path[name path=ba] (B) -- ++ (45:5.5);
\path[name path=ca] (C) -- ++ (140:5.5);
\path[name intersections={of = ba and ca, by=A}] node[circle, inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=3pt]above right:{$\large\boldsymbol{A}$}}] at (A) {};
% triangle's edges
\draw[->,thick] (A)--(B)--(C)--($(C)!1.4!(A)$);
%%%%%%%
\draw[->,thick] (C) -- ($(C)!1.3!(B)$);
\node[circle, inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=5pt]below:{$\large\boldsymbol{E}$}},left=3.5 of C] (E) {};
\path[name path=ed] (E) -- ++ (155:4);
\path[name intersections={of = ed and ba, by=D}] node[circle, inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=0pt]above left:{$\large\boldsymbol{D}$}}] at (D) {};
\draw[-,thick] (E)--(D);
% angles
\pic [myangle, "$\large\boldsymbol{s}$",angle radius=5mm] {angle = E--B--D};
\pic [myangle, "\ang{25}"] {angle = D--E--B};
\pic [myangle, "\ang{70}"] {angle = E--D--A};
\pic [myangle, "\ang{40}"] {angle = A--C--E};
\node[circle, inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=0pt]below:{}}] (Q) at ($(C)!1.4!(A)$) {};
\pic [myangle, "$\large\boldsymbol{r}$",angle radius=5mm] {angle = Q--A--B};
% triangle height
%\draw[dashed] (A) -- (A |- B) coordinate[label=below:H] (H);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output:


I'm glad that you solve your problem yourself! +1
